# Flutter GridView.builder, la segunda columna no responde a los taps correctamente

Tags: flutter, widget, card

Estoy trabajando con Flutter 3.3.9.
tengo una lista tipo StaggeredDualView (creado con los ejercicios de @diegoveloper),esta lista me muestra dos columnas.Cada item es un Card envuelto en un GestureDetector y todo iba bien (sin problema), pero ahora que necesito agregar mas botones dentro del Card, a manera de ejemplo e agregado un IconButton.
La primera columna trabaja bien, si hago click dentro de IconButton, se ejecuta bien,
y si hago click fuera del IconButton se ejecuta el GestureDetector correctamente.
pero en la segunda columna si hago click en el IconButton no hace nada, si hago click fuera del IconButton si se ejecuta el GestureDetector.
No consigo hacer que funcione el IconButton ni cualquier widget  ya he probado con distintos widgets, MaterialButton, InkWell, IconButton. lo raro es que en la primera columna si funciona y en la segunda columna no.

aquí la clase que crea el StaggeredDualView.

```
 class StaggeredDualView extends StatelessWidget {
      const StaggeredDualView(
          {super.key,
          required this.itemBuilder,
          required this.itemCount,
          this.spacing = 0.0,
          this.aspectRatio = 0.5,
          this.offsetPercent = 0.5});
    
      final IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;
      final int itemCount;
      final double spacing;
      final double aspectRatio;
      final double offsetPercent;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return LayoutBuilder(builder: (contex, constraints) {
          final width = constraints.maxWidth;
          final itemHeight = (width * 0.5) / aspectRatio;
          final height = constraints.maxHeight + itemHeight;
          return OverflowBox(
            maxWidth: width,
            minWidth: width,
            maxHeight: height,
            minHeight: height,
            child: GridView.builder(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: itemHeight / 2, bottom: itemHeight),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: aspectRatio,
                  crossAxisSpacing: spacing,
                  mainAxisSpacing: spacing,
                ),
                itemCount: itemCount,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(
                          0.0, index.isOdd ? itemHeight * offsetPercent : 0.0),
                      child: itemBuilder(context, index));
                }),
          );
        });
      }
    }
```

Aqui el BUILD del statefull Widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: cartBarHeight, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 120),
        child: StaggeredDualView(
          // aspectRatio: 0.7,
          aspectRatio: responsive.isTablet ? 20 / 9 : 0.7,
          offsetPercent: 0.3,
          spacing: 20,
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final product = products[index]!;

            return ProductCard(
              showClientPrice: true,
              product: product,
              itemCount: products.length,
              onTap: () async {
                print('InkWell ONTAP presionado');
                bloc.add(ChangeToDetails());
                await Navigator.of(context).push(
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                    pageBuilder: (context, animation, __) {
                      return FadeTransition(
                        opacity: animation,
                        child: GroceryStoreDetails(
                          product: product,
                          onProductAdded: (int quantity) {
                            bloc.add(AddProduct(product, quantity));
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
                bloc.add(ChangeToNormal());
              },

            );
          },

        ),
      );
```

y ahora el CARD

```
class ProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.product,
    this.widget,
    this.showClientPrice = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Widget? widget;
  final bool showClientPrice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final hasDiscount = (product.clientPrice != 0 &&
        product.clientPrice != product.price &&
        showClientPrice);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        elevation: 8,
        shadowColor: Colors.black45,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'list_${product.id}',
                  child: (product.images.isNotEmpty)
                      ? CachedImage(
                          fromUrl: product.images[0],
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        )
                      : const CachedImage(
                          fromUrl: null,
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'PG \$${product.price}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: (hasDiscount)
                      ? Colors.red.withOpacity(0.40)
                      : Colors.black,
                  decoration: (hasDiscount) ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
                  fontSize: (product.clientPrice != 0) ? 16 : 20,
                ),
              ),
              if (hasDiscount)
                Text(
                  '\$${product.clientPrice}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text(
                '[${product.provcode}] ${product.name}',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 11,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                product.descr,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('biclieta presionada');
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.pedal_bike)),
              // if (widget != null)
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print(' gesture dector');
                  },
                  child: Text('sdf')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

se ve así

[image: StaggeredDualView]

Si hago click en cualquier bicicleta de la primera columna el debug console muestra esto.
Pongo ***** a lo que el debug reacciona cuando hago click

```
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 0)
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 1)*
I/flutter (28204): biclieta presionada
```

si hago click en cualquier card fuera dela bicicleta va bien también.

```
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 0)
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 1)*
I/flutter (28204): InkWell ONTAP presionado
```

Ahora click en los card de la segunda Columna,
Si hago click en el cualquier card fuera de la bicicleta de la segunda columna Si se ejecuta:

```
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 0)
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 1)*
I/flutter (28204): InkWell ONTAP presionado
```

PERO si hago click en el icono de la bicicleta no se ejecuta el callback,
pero el log si me muestra actividad-

```
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 0)
*****(I/ViewRootImpl@4949368[MainActivity](28204): ViewPostIme pointer 1)*
```

aqui me deberia de mostrar **I/flutter (28204): biclieta presionada** pero no lo hace

ya intente hacer varias cosas, pero no me funciona.
desde ya gracias

Comment: De hecho no recomiendo esa forma en que lo hice, solo fue para demostrar que se puede mostrar listas escalonadas con Transform, pero al mover ese elemento a otra posición con Transform, se pierde el Gesture en la parte que este fuera del elemento (sin transform), te recomiendo usar este package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: Muchas gracias @diegoveloper.